# How to match dates from Table A with a date range in Table B and bring corresponding data from Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Table A

```
**ID      empID       log_date_time**
1        1234        2019-10-06 01:00  
2        1234        2019-10-07 03:00
```

Table B

```
**empID          start_date_time     end_date_time**
1234           2019-10-06 22:00    2019-10-07 02:00
```

Expected output

Table C

```
**ID      empID       log_date_time         within_range_flag**
1        1234        2019-10-06 01:00            1
2        1234        2019-10-07 03:00            0
```

There are around 10,000,000 records in Table A and 15,000 records in Table B. 
I have tried joins but it seems to take forever to process.

Any idea how to match Table A date time with Table B's date time range?

Thank you.

---edit 
I would also need to bring in Table B's information for reference purpose. So the expected output is

Table C

```
**ID      empID       log_date_time         within_range_flag         start_date_time     end_date_time**
1        1234        2019-10-06 01:00            1                  2019-10-06 22:00    2019-10-07 02:00
2        1234        2019-10-07 03:00            0                  2019-10-06 22:00    2019-10-07 02:00
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `>`/`>=` and `<`/`<=` operators?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the operators. I had difficulty in comparing data from another table. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    ID, empID, log_date_time,
    case when start_date_time is null then 0 else 1 end within_range_flag, start_date_time
from (
  select a.ID, a.empID, log_date_time, min(start_date_time) start_date_time
  from tableA a
  left join tableB b on b.empID = a.empID
    and a.log_date_time between b.start_date_time and b.end_date_time
  group by a.ID, a.empID, log_date_time
) x
```

This works by collapsing all joining tableB rows to just one value using aggregation to get the earliest `start_date_time`. If there isn't any joniing rows, `start_date_time` will be `null` and you can use that fact to produce the flag value.

This assumes you want the earliest `start_date_time` of all the matching rows from tableB. If you want the latest, use `max()`. If you want something different, don't use this query.

You should create an index on `tableB(empId, start_date_time, end_date_time)`.

---

In the case where there is at most 1 row in `tableB` that joins, the query may be simplified by eliminating the inner query (and will likely execute faster):

```
select
    a.ID, a.empID, log_date_time,
    case when start_date_time is null then 0 else 1 end within_range_flag,
    start_date_time
from tableA a
left join tableB b on b.empID = a.empID
    and a.log_date_time between b.start_date_time and b.end_date_time
```

Comment: There is only one start_date_time per day in Table B so I guess this could work well. I will experiment it on actual data set.

Comment: @cyber is it true that there is either exactly 1 join or no join to tableB from any row in tableA?

Comment: Yes,either exactly 1 join or no join to table B from any row in table A. Thank you very much.

Comment: @cyberwalk the simpler query I added may work even better for you.

Comment: I will try it out. Thank you so much!

Comment: The simpler query works perfectly well. Thank you and wish you have a happy new year!

Comment: @cyberwalk no problem. Happy new year to you too!

Answer (score 0):

The canonical solution would be:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from tableB b
                          where b.empId = a.empId and
                                a.log_date_time between b.start_date_time and b.end_date_time
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as in_range
from tableA a;
```

For this query, I would recommend an index on `tableB(empId, start_date_time, end_date_time)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply. I think adding an index could be useful for bringing data from Table B as well. I will try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
select a.ID,
       a.empID,
       a.log_date_time,
       x.within_range_flag,
       x.start_date_time,
       x.end_date_time
from Table_A a
     outer apply (
       select b.start_date_time,
              b.end_date_time,
              case when a.log_date_time between b.start_date_time and b.end_date_time
                   then 1 else 0 end as within_range_flag
       from Table_b b
       where a.empID = b.empID
      ) x
```

Comment: It's getting closer. But it seems that outer apply generated a lot of duplication. Will continue to work on it. Thank you.

Comment: @cyberwalk Ok, i add new answer which is good. It's just a normal join. I tried it by myself at MSSQL.

Comment: Why `OUTER APPLY` instead of a straightforward `LEFT JOIN`?  If you were linking to a function I could understand its use, but it escapes me here.   Just [dropping the code in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) isn't really an answer; an explanation of your reasoning is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is correct answer :

```
   select a.ID,
          a.empID,
          a.log_date_time,
          case 
          when a.log_date_time between B.start_date_time and b.end_date_time then 1 
          else 0 
          end as within_range_flag,
          b.start_date_time,
          b.end_date_time
   from Table_A a
   left join Table_B b on b.empID = a.empID
```

Comment: Thank you for trying. Unfortunately, left join also returned duplication as each row in Table A matches all rows in Table B for each empID.

Comment: @cyberwalk Are you sure, you don't have duplication as section time? I mean for example : start -> 2019-10-07 2:00, end -> 2019-10-08 22:00 and start -> 2019-10-08 20:00 , end -> 2019-10-09 23:00 ?